# Do the quality filters really work?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, quality, quality-filter

I just discovered [this user](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/14941/siddharth) on gamedev.SE. The user has asked 7 questions, with scores of 0, 0, -1, -2, -4, -5, and -5, and provided 3 answers with scores of 0, 0, and -2.

- <strike>How does a user with a net of -19 votes have more than 1 reputation?</strike>
- How does a user with a net of -19 not have some kind of suspension (resulting in low-rep users like myself seeing a simple 1-rep suspended profile)?

Is this something the quality filters should be picking up but missed, or are the quality filters aimed lower than I thought?

Comment: A user's reputation will **never** go below 1.

Comment: You couldn't tell if he'd been automatically banned from asking questions. Even moderators can't see that information on a user's profile. So, in fact, the quality filters might be working just fine. They don't cause the user to be *suspended*: that's not an automatic action, but rather one undertaken by a moderator.

Comment: I've narrowed my question down a bit (it kind of asked two questions, but the answer to the first was simple enough that I probably should have left it out in the first place)

Comment: @TheEstablishment I thought suspended users [have their reputation locked at 1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) (see: Penalty Box)

Comment: Yes, *suspended* users do. This is the same as being placed into the penalty box. That's something that a moderator does manually. This is *different* from an automatic ban on asking questions, which is applied by the system automatically if you have a history of low-quality contributions. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) for details.

Comment: @TheEstablishment Ok, so bans are automatic, and invisible to other users. Suspensions (done manually by mods) are not. I get it. I'm just kind of confused that a user can have 10 posts with an average score less than -1 without *already* being auto-question/answer-banned.

Comment: @Jim: Well, that was my point. How do you know he's *not* been automatically question-banned? (The question and answer bans are two separate things.) Has he posted another question in the meantime?

Comment: Question bans are only enabled on a few sites, I don't think they're active on Gamedev anyway.

Comment: Oh yeah, @Fabian is right, too. I erroneously assumed you were talking about Stack Overflow here. I don't think the automatic question/answer bans are active very many other places, if any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the site has an extremely high volume of questions, we don't like to enable the automated protection for *askers*.

Logic being, on a small-ish volume site, some of those poor questions can potentially be whipped into shape via editing, whereas on Stack Overflow at 4-5k questions *per day* we can afford to throw a <s>lot</s> few away.

There is more automated protection around answers.

Bottom line, on smaller sites this should be handled through community intervention more than algorithms. If you think the user is harming the site, **don't hesitate to flag them for moderator attention**.

Answer (score 3):

Upvotes are worth more positive than downvotes are negative - +5 for a question upvote and +10 for an answer while downvotes are only -2.  Look at [**the user's reputation history**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/14941/siddharth?tab=reputation).  It clearly shows the values that result in the (currently) +4 reputation.

Comment: OK, yes, it does. But how does this string of posts get past the SE quality filters?